# How to get audit trail info from Opentext Content Mgmt Server? Is there any RestAPI?

Tags: opentext

Opentext provides 2 techiniques to get information from Content Servers.
1. RestAPI
2. CMIS

Is there any way to get the audit information from any of these 2 methods.
As per CMIS support, Opentext doesn't support changes capability. But still is there any way?

Is there any RestAPI?

Thanks 
Muthu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version are you on? ReST API were introduced in the Update 2014-09 (September).
There is another way to communicate with CS - Soap Webservices.
Do you or your company have an support contract with Open Text? If so, you can check the Knowledge Centre under https://knowledge.opentext.com.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steffen for your reply.<br/> Actually, I am currently exploring way to integrate OpenText with one of a application which captures audit trail and gives different stats. So no Support contract with opentext as of now. But can you please confirm whether its possible using CS-Soap Webservices.

Comment: Yes you can. Look into the DocMan service.